# Displaying fields based on user's current location in Microsoft Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

Is there a way that the user who is accessing the dashboard/report on Power BI Desktop gets displayed values only relevant to his region?

I've tried using query parameters but was just wondering if there is any other way to dynamically allow the location to be updated depending on the location of the user who opens the .pbix file/Dashboard on BI Service.

Comment: You need to publish your report to service and implement RLS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls